# What happens to the eigenvalues of a matrix with reciprocal off diagonal blocks when I premultiply by a diagonal matrix with binary diagonal entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ in the form $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-I & C\\C^{-1} & -I\end{bmatrix}$$ (I am assuming C is square and nonsingular) and a diagonal $n\times n$ matrix $B$ with diagonal entries $B_{ii}\in\{0,1\}$.

It is straightforward to show that $A$ has eigenvalues that are either equal to $0$ or $-2$ (i.e., one can show that no matter the invertible $C$ chosen, the eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix}O & C\\C^{-1} & O\end{bmatrix}$ are either $1$ or $-1$).

What can I say about the eigenvalues of $BA$?

Clearly $A$ is not symmetric (and $B$ is singular in the practical cases where I need it) in general so classical relations and bounds on the eigenvalues of $BA$ in terms of those of $B$ and $A$ hardly apply.

For sure any zero eigenvalue of $A$ is preserved as a zero eigenvalue of $BA$ so $BA$ has as least as many zero eigenvalues as $A$. What can I say about nonzero eigenvalues?

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

Let $P$ be the $n\times n$ permutation matrix such that
$$P^{-1}BP=
\begin{bmatrix}I & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and
$$P^{-1}AP=\widehat{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}\widehat{A}_{11} & \widehat{A}_{12}\\\widehat{A}_{21} & \widehat{A}_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$

Matrix $BA$ is similar to
$$P^{-1}BAP=P^{-1}BPP^{-1}AP=
\begin{bmatrix}\widehat{A}_{11} & \widehat{A}_{12}\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

so, being the above matrix upper block triangular, it holds

$$
\sigma(BA)=\sigma(\widehat{A}_{11})\cup\{0\},
$$
where $\sigma(X)$ stands for the spectrum of $X$.

In other words, the problem ultimately reduces to finding the eigenvalues of the leading principal minor $\widehat{A}_{11}$ of $\widehat{A}$.
Unfortunately $\widehat{A}$ is not in general symmetric and thus usual interlacing theorems do not apply (at least, I do not know something right-to-be-used).

I thought of using Bauer-Fike Theorem but I got stuck.

Comment: it would be better to ask about $A' :=\frac{-1}{2}A$ and what about the eigenvalues of $BA'$ as both $B$ and $A'$ are idempotent. I don't think there is much that can be said about the eigenvalues of $BA'$ when they are non-commuting